# Change background color Java Me

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me

I am developing a j2me midlet application with netbeans how ever I am new to java but I have developed all things i need. But I cannot change background color or image when I run the jar file on mobile it show a transparent or white color background is there any possible way to change background color or image any answered will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do anything about the background when working with High Level GUI (meaning `Form` stuff).
If you want to control the background, you'll need to use `Canvas` - but `Form` elements can't be used on a `Canvas`.
Best option then is to use LWUIT. It gives you a set of elements like you have with `Form`, but because it uses `Canvas` you have much more options and such.

Comment: For somebody new to Java, I don't recommend using LWUIT. You need some experience first, otherwise you will get lost.